# how to give space between two rows of bootstrap while working with forms

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing the **bootstrap** form but its not a working correctly , its `row space` not working, how can i fix it? i need to make space in this rows,please help me to fix it. I'm trying to make but not working
thanks in advance.

Please view this link:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/dp3ugL97/)

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">Company<b style=" color:#ff0000;">*</b>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">

    <input id="firstname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="firstname" title="Enter first name" placeholder="First name">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">Godown Code<b style=" color:#ff0000;">*</b>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">

    <input id="lastname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="lastname" title="Enter last name" placeholder="Last name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">Godown Code<b style=" color:#ff0000;">*</b>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">

      <input id="firstname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="firstname" title="Enter first name" placeholder="First name">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">Godown Code<b style=" color:#ff0000;">*</b>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">

      <input id="lastname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="lastname" title="Enter last name" placeholder="Last name">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">Godown Code<b style=" color:#ff0000;">*</b>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">

    <input id="firstname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="firstname" title="Enter first name" placeholder="First name">
  </div>

</div>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please edit your code

Comment: are you talking about the space between the input box and the label ??

Comment: if you read the bootstrap document carefully, its mentioned to use `form-group` as parent class for form elements like `input` or `textarea`, which gives a `margin-bottom:15px` and creates a space, and this `form-group` class also helpful for showing validation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your problem you should give following css. It will make proper space between row.

```
.col-md-3 {
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp3ugL97/1/)**

Comment: Wish your Happy New year :) Thanks for the help  , now it's working

Comment: yeah sure, wait for 5 minutes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please check [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) for form control.